# Metamask is not showing my balance - emergency question for a newbie

Tags: metamask, wallets, balances

I have been using Metamask for a few days now, and I'm experiencing an issue. The Ethereum balances in my Metamask account are not showing up and it says I have zero Ether. However, when I check on Etherscan, it clearly shows that I have some Ethereum in my account.

How can I resolve this issue?

Another question I have is why, when I search for my own account address on Etherscan, it shows me different accounts with various balances.

I would appreciate your response as I have tried various methods but none of them have provided a solution.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are on the correct network in MetaMask. When you open your MetaMask, click the little downwards arrow that's just before your account and switch to the network that you need to see the balance for.

MetaMask is pulling the account balance through an endpoint of a blockchain node that has the network state. For example, if your account has zero ETH on Optimism and your MetaMask is on Optimisim, you will see zero. And if you have an amount on the Ethereum mainnet, switch to the Ethereum mainnet and it should pull the balance correctly and display it to you.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I find out which network is the one that can show my correct balance?
Is there a way to find out on etherscan?

Answer (score 0):

Go to metamask and on the top left side there is network tab . Select Ethereum mainnet on it . Here is an attached photo

[image]